# Footer underneath 3 div columns?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to put the footer underneath ALL my 3 `div` columns, I believe it has something to do with the height.. when I make the `div wrapper 600px` it works & goes underneath all 3 but when the middle `div` is taller then `600px` it goes under the right div, what could i do so it goes underneath all three?

the html:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 

    <div class="left">
    </div>

    <div class="middle">

   <p>
        example
    <p>
        example
    <p>
        example
    <p>
        example
    <p>
        example
    <p>
       example
    <p>


    </div>

    <div class="right">
    </div>


    </div> 

    </body>

    <footer> whaat </footer>
```

the css:

```
body {
    margin: 45px auto;
    background: #CCC;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    }

.wrapper { 
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 1000px; 
    max-width: 1500px; 
    margin: 0px auto;}

.left, .middle, .right { 
    float:left; }

.left, .right { 
    width: 16%; 
    padding:5px; 
    }

.middle  { 
    background: #f1f1f1; 
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 12px -2px #FFF;
    width: 65%; 
    padding:5px; 
    text-align:center; 
}

.left { background: #00F }
.right { background: #00F}
```

Comment: `footer{clear:both;}` add this to your code.!! [Output of the changes made](http://jsfiddle.net/Fwn6q/1/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

You have no styling on the footer, could add:

```
footer{
   clear:both;
   width:100%;
}
```

The `clear:both` property [prevents the element it is applied to from having floating elements appear alongside it in the specified direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear). For `clear:both;`, nothing can float on *either* side of the element.
The `width:100%` will make the div stretch the width of the window, can edit as needed.
Also, you don't want to close the body before the footer...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `clear:left` in `footer`. Because you are using `float:left` property in your CSS. So to clear float you can use either `overflow:hidden` on your main `container` div.

Another solution is you can use a `display:table` and `display-table-cell` CSS property to make this kind of layout. the good thing is by this method all `3 columns` will have `equal height`.

> **Note:**  In addition in your HTML code `</body>` tag should closed after
>   `footer` tag.

Check The **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jaxuwoqa/1/edit)**.

```
footer{background:gold; clear:left;}
```

Comment: Does it helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the div

Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/elfbq)

```
.wrapper:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position: relative and overflow: hidden in Wrapper CSS like this:

```
.wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1500px;
min-width: 1000px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/79bA4/1/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle">
        <p>example</p>
        <p>example</p>
        <p>example</p>
        <p>example</p>
        <p>example</p>
        <p>example</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <footer>whaat</footer>
</div>
```

css

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    background: #CCC;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.left, .middle, .right {
    float:left;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
.left, .right {
    width: 17%; 
}
.middle {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    width: 66%;
    text-align:center;
}
.left {
    background: #00F
}
.right {
    background: #00F
}
footer {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```